# Xamarin.Forms block UI when ItemsSource load a big data

Tags: visual-studio, api, xaml, xamarin.forms, async-await

I do not load a small data from the API, in C# code, they are loaded in advance and everything seems to be fine, but as soon as I open the page where ItemsSource = "{Binding BigData}", my UI is blocked for 10 seconds.
Are there any ideas to open the page first, then start loading data without blocking the UI?

Comment: I guess you use `CollectionView` and `Group` right?

Comment: I think you can use `PaginatedList` not to set the `ItemsSource` one time but set 10 or 20 each time. when user scroll to display more you can add more data.

Comment: I used ListView, StackLayout and List<T> with a big data.
Thanks, i will try to use PaginatedList and will write to here.

Comment: I noticed one thing: when I run the application through Visual Studio, the UI hangs, and without it, everything is fine. Is that how it should be?

Comment: You run it in debug mode then it will hang? without debug and run it will not hang right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would to suggest you can kick off a task in your view models constructor that loads the data. Using Async and await to load bid data.

I do one sample that using ListView to display 100000 records.

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="test ui in xamarin.forms asyn" />
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding isBusy}" IsVisible="{Binding isBusy}" />
        <ListView x:Name="listview1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding name}" />
                            <Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="{Binding age}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

  public partial class Page19 : ContentPage
{      
    public Page19()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    
        this.BindingContext = new ItemsViewModel();
    }    
}
public class ItemsViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isBusy;
    public bool isBusy
    {
        get { return _isBusy; }
        set
        {
            _isBusy = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("isBusy");
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<people> Items { get; set; }
    public ItemsViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<people>();
        isBusy = true;
        Task.Run(async () => await LoadItems());
    }

    public async Task LoadItems()
    {
       var items = new ObservableCollection<people>(); // new collection
        if (isBusy)
        {               
            await Task.Delay(10000);
            // var loadedItems = ItemsService.LoadItemsDirectory();
            //foreach (var item in loadedItems)
            //    items.Add(item);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                people p = new people();
                p.name = "people " + i;
                p.age = i;
                items.Add(p); // items are added to the new collection    
            }            
            Items = items; // swap the collection for the new one
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Items));  // raise a property change in whatever way is right for your VM

            isBusy = false;
        }
    }
}
public class people
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModelBase is one class that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged

```
 public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{       
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;       
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```